# AngularJS: multiples views using same controller best practice

Tags: angularjs

I've made an app with 3 slightly different views which use the same logic, so each one uses the same controller, but have different json data. Everything is working fine, but I was wondering if it is AngularJS best practice to do so ? 
When routes change, does the view replaced uses the same instance of the controller, or does it instantiate a new controller ?

Thanx.

Comment: In my small experience, each time a view changes, its controller was reloaded. I'm using ui-router, so maybe AngularJs basic routes don't have the same behavior.
You can put "console.log" in your controller to detect this.

Comment: I wondered the same about here is some helpful info [Angular Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20802798/1959948)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new controller is created each time a view is loaded--controllers are transient in this sense.  If state needs to be maintained, you should use a service or factory.

I personally will share controllers between different variations of the same view.  In a general sense, if the controller represents the same logic (or abstraction) in relation to the view, I see no reason not to re-use it.